# How do I remove offsetting rows in a tibble?

Tags: r

I am trying to remove rows that have offsetting values.

```
library(dplyr)
a <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,2,2)
b <- c("a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c","c", "d", "d", "d")
d <- c(10, 10, -10, 10, 20, -20, 20, 30, -30, 30)
o <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")
df <- tibble(ID = a, SEQ = b, VALUE = d, OTHER = o)
```

Generates this ordered table that is grouped by ID and SEQ.

```
> df
# A tibble: 10 x 4
      ID   SEQ VALUE OTHER
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
 1     1     a    10     A
 2     1     b    10     B
 3     1     b   -10     C
 4     1     b    10     D
 5     2     c    20     E
 6     2     c   -20     F
 7     2     c    20     G
 8     2     d    30     H
 9     2     d   -30     I
10     2     d    30     J
```

I want to drop the row pairs (2,3), (5,6), (8,9) because VALUE negates the VALUE in the matching previous row.

I want the resulting table to be

```
> df2
# A tibble: 4 x 4
     ID   SEQ VALUE OTHER
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     a    10     A
2     1     b    10     D
3     2     c    20     G
4     2     d    30     J
```

I know that I can't use `group_by %>% summarize`, because I need to keep the value that is in OTHER.  I've looked at the `dplyr::lag()` function but I don't see how that can help.  I believe that I could loop through the table with some type of `for each` loop and generate a logical vector that can be used to drop the rows, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: It seems like you asked a question, got an answer, accepted the answer, and several hours later you are editing the question. This is bad - it is "moving the goal posts". Instead, I would recommend creating a new question, linking to this one, and explaining why the original answer didn't work.

Comment: Thanks - Will try to revert and follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
vec <- cbind(
               c(head(df$VALUE,-1) + df$VALUE[-1], 9999) ,
               df$VALUE + c(9999, head(df$VALUE,-1))
             )

vec <- apply(vec,1,prod)
vec <- vec!=0
df[vec,]
# A tibble: 4 x 4
     ID   SEQ VALUE OTHER
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     a    10     A
2     1     b    50     D
3     2     c    60     G
4     2     d    70     J
```

The idea is to take your `VALUE` field and subtract it with a slightly subset version of it.  When the result is 0, than you remove the line.

Comment: Nice, your solution even worked on an edge case I just discovered.  I am going to apply it to my real world problem and see what happens.

Comment: If you find problem with it, try to identify the problems and make them reproducible in your example.

Comment: made some modifications, it's pretty much the same idea, but I have to do the trick twice.  It's not really elegant but it should be more robust.  Just adapt the `9999` value so it's not a problem with your actual data.  I've added this to have a `length=10` vector.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution with `dplyr`. Not sure about the edge case you mentioned in the comments, but feel free to test it with my solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, SEQ) %>%
  mutate(diff = VALUE + lag(VALUE),
         diff2 = VALUE + lead(VALUE)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(diff:diff2), funs(coalesce(., 1))) %>%
  filter((diff != 0 & diff2 != 0)) %>%
  select(-diff, -diff2)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   ID, SEQ [4]
     ID   SEQ VALUE OTHER
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     a    10     A
2     1     b    50     D
3     2     c    60     G
4     2     d    70     J
```

**Note:**

This solution first creates two `diff` columns, one adding the `lag`, another adding the `lead` of `VALUE` to each `VALUE`. Only the offset columns will either have a zero in `diff` or in `diff2`, so I filtered out those rows, resulting in the desired output.

Comment: I didn't know about `lead` and `lag`.  It's good to know, thanks.

Comment: Could this be adjusted to account for instances in which there may be multiple positive VALUE followed by multiple negative?  for example, five rows with matching ID and SEQ with the VALUE being (20, 20, 20, -20, -20).  I would want to keep one row and remove the duplicates but wouldn't the lead/lag be confused by the order