# Removing offsetting rows in a tibble

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

**Please note that the order of the data and the VALUE column are different from my prior question. [How do I remove offsetting rows in a tibble?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47756408/2359914)  The accepted answer for the question works for the data set I provided, however changing values causes the answer to fail.**

I am trying to remove rows that have offsetting values.

```
library(dplyr)
a <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,2,2)
b <- c("a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c","c", "d", "d", "d")
d <- c(10, 10, -10, 50, 20, -20, 60, 30, -30, 70)
o <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")
df <- tibble(ID = a, SEQ = b, VALUE = d, OTHER = o)
```

Generates this ordered table that is grouped by ID and SEQ.

```
> df
# A tibble: 10 x 4
      ID   SEQ VALUE OTHER
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
 1     1     a    10     A
 2     1     b   -10     B
 3     1     b    10     C
 4     1     b    50     D
 5     2     c   -20     E
 6     2     c    20     F
 7     2     c    60     G
 8     2     d   -30     H
 9     2     d    30     I
10     2     d    70     J
```

I want to drop the row pairs (2,3), (5,6), (8,9) because VALUE negates the VALUE in the matching previous row.

I want the resulting table to be

```
> df2
# A tibble: 4 x 4
     ID   SEQ VALUE OTHER
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     a    10     A
2     1     b    50     D
3     2     c    60     G
4     2     d    70     J
```

I know that I can't use `group_by %>% summarize`, because I need to keep the value that is in OTHER.  I've looked at the `dplyr::lag()` function but I don't see how that can help.  I believe that I could loop through the table with some type of `for each` loop and generate a logical vector that can be used to drop the rows, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove offsetting rows in a tibble?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47756408/how-do-i-remove-offsetting-rows-in-a-tibble)

Comment: I don't see how this is any different from your previous question.

Comment: Should I have revised the data set provided with my original question?

Comment: I guess you got negative feedback about that on the other question. So not sure what the right strategy would have been. The two questions are the same question, and it just turns out to be the case that the accepted answer was not sufficiently general, so it shouldn't have been accepted in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I completely misunderstood your question, does this do the job?

```
idx <- which(diff(cumsum(df$VALUE)) < 0);
df[-c(idx, idx + 1), ];
## A tibble: 4 x 4
#     ID   SEQ VALUE OTHER
#  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
#1     1     a    10     A
#2     1     b    50     D
#3     2     c    60     G
#4     2     d    70     J
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution which does not have any assumptions unlike the accepted answer which assumes:

1- Data is also ordered based on `VALUE`

2- Whenever the difference of `cumsum` is negative that means that the value has been negated comparing to the previous row.

3- And if the difference is negative, those rows are in the same group (somewhat acceptable based on ordered data provided).

The more general answer would be:

```
df %>% arrange(ID,SEQ,VALUE) %>%  group_by(ID, SEQ) %>% 
              mutate(helper = VALUE + lag(VALUE, default = -999)) %>% 
              filter(!(helper==0 | lead(helper, default = -999)==0)) %>% select(-helper))
## # A tibble: 4 x 4
## # Groups:   ID, SEQ [4]
##      ID   SEQ VALUE OTHER
##   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
## 1     1     a    10     A
## 2     1     b    50     D
## 3     2     c    60     G
## 4     2     d    70     J
```

Comment: I agree that your solution is more general; but according to OP: *"I want to drop the row pairs (2,3), (5,6), (8,9) because VALUE negates the VALUE in the matching previous row."* So that implies assumptions 1 and 2. Not sure what you're point is in assumption 3.

Comment: Yes, the order of the rows is important.  The only difference between the rows for this sample data is the VALUE column.  Sometimes I may even have two rows which cancel out and no third row to take their place. (And I really hope I am explaining that correctly.) M. Evers solution does take care of that for me.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I am not sure how what you quoted implies that data is sorted based on value. About the 2nd assumption that's completely embedded in your solution and has nothing to do with the question. You assumed that if `cumsum()` is less than 0, then that means `val1 = -val2` but actually that means `val2 < 0`. Anyways, this is nothing personal. I just provided a more general idea while your answer has been already accepted by OP. Cheers.

Comment: @Masoud No offence taken at all. I like your solution.